# Data loading asynchronously and not displaying in UITabBarController TableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, asynchronous, firebase

My application is a `UITabBarController` application and when it first begins, it needs to make a call my `Firebase` database so that I can populate the `UITableView` within one of the tabs in the `UITabBarController`. However, I noticed that the first time I login and go to the `TabBarController`, the data does not show. I have to go from that tab to another tab, and then back to the original tab to have the data be displayed. However, I want it so that the data displays the first time around. I understand this is an error with the fact that Firebase asynchronously grabs data and that the view loads before all the data is processed but I just can't seem to get it to work as desired.

I tried to query for all the values we want first before we perform the segue, store them into an array, and then send that array to a predefined array in `OffersView` but that did not seem to work. Here is my attempt:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "OffersView"){
      let barViewControllers = segue.destinationViewController as UITabBarController
        let navigationOfferController = barViewControllers.viewControllers![0] as UINavigationController
        let offersViewController = navigationOfferController.topViewController as OffersView
        offersViewController.offers = offersQuery()
    }

func offersQuery() -> [Offer]{

    firebaseRef = Firebase(url:"https://OffersDB.firebaseio.com/offers")

    //Read the data at our posts reference
    firebaseRef.observeEventType(FEventType.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in

        let restaurant = snapshot.value["restaurant"] as? String


        let offer = Offer(restaurant: restaurant)

        //Maintain array of offers
        self.offers.append(offer)
        }) { (error) -> Void in
            println(error.description)
    }
    return offers
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: Im trying to use a completion handler everytime the childAdded call occurs and I am trying to do it like so but I can't seem to get it to work. I get an error saying: `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 1 into section 0, but there are only 1 rows in section 0 after the update`

```
setupOffers { (result) -> Void in
        if(result == true){
            var row = self.offers.count
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            var indexPaths = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0)
            println(indexPaths)
            self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPaths], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should segue normally, and inside the UITableViewController, perform the query. Once the query callback is called, you can go ahead and reload the table with `-reloadData` so it will populate the cells.

Comment: How can I know when my query callback is successfully finished? That is the part I am struggling with. Also I am not using a UITableViewController, I'm just using a TableView (not sure if that changes anything though).

Comment: What you can do is that or each time FEventType.ChildAdded is called, you want to perform `-insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to the tableView after you update the model. This way your offers load smoothly one by one into the tableView without you having to batch update with a completion handler.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. I'll try to work on an implementation and get back to you if I can't seem to make it work. I was wondering, could you give me some tips on how to do a batch update with a completion handler though? I'm a bit new to Swift so I don't know what that entirely entails.

Comment: Also, how do we know when FEventType.ChildAdded is finished calling? just at the end of the function declaration?

Comment: I don't use firebase but I assume that every child added calls the method. You don't need to wait until the method calls finish before you populate the tableView.

Comment: Hi, I'm having some issues with the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation` call. What I did was I set a completion handler after every childAdded function was called but then I keep getting an error saying that I am trying to insert a row into section 0 but there are only 1 rows in section 0 after update. My attempt is in the edit above.

Comment: Are you adding the object into your model (i.e. your array of objects)? It seems like that you call the method but `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` still returns the old amount (so the adding fails)